# AngularJs sorting nested multidimensional JSON data by property

Tags: angularjs, sorting, multidimensional-array, angularjs-orderby

I have **nested multidimensional JSON** data from an **API url**. I have been able to loop and display all the data with **angularjs** using four **nested ng-repeat** rows. I have tried to sort the data by a specific property with **orderBy**. Sorting is working fine in second ng-repeat row: `orderBy : 'person.lastName'` but for some reason the same sorting is not working with the fourth ng-repeat row, for example: `orderBy : 'stat.points'`. Thanks for everyone who could help!

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/WallE91FIN/pen/XERyOM) test project.

Comment: There's no data in your codepen. If we don't know the structure of your data, we can't help you. And please, use the correct tags next time.

Comment: where is the  nested multidimensional JSON data ?

Comment: (for the CodePen to work, change `http://statsapi.web.nhl.com` to `https://statsapi.web.nhl.com`)

Comment: Now the link should be working, Thanks Aleksey!

Comment: I think you need to make your own orderBy filter. Imagine you have `b={"stat":{"points":[1,2,3]}}` with `orderBy:'stat.points'`, I believe it will try to do `b["stat.points"]`, which gives _undefined_ due to a wrong syntax.

Comment: @WallE you can't do ordering like `stat.points` ang doesn't support it .

Comment: Ok, thanks super cool for your answer, good to know if angular does not support that type of ordering.